# How to open a custom project overview page when the project is loaded from the custom project template

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, vs-extensibility, vsixmanifest

Where to add a custom page and open it when the custom project template is loaded within the visual studio. For example below is the project home page when an MVC project template is opened in visual studio, similarly I have a requirement to open such a custom page for my project template.

I know that the below MVC project home page markup, styles, resources and manifest files are located at "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\Project\Overview". How does the microsoft predefined templates loaded such home page? what is the starting point? Are they using any tool or library which does it?

[image]

Comment: When you creae a mvc project, the mechanism will generate a project-based overciew page based on your information combined with the background master page. This mechanism is internal to vs and is not available. And if you want to get the generated overview page, you'll find that it's not a form itself (hover over the header and it's called xxx.csproj) and doesn't exist. So you can't open it through the API. Perhaps if you want to modify this overview page, you can directly  modify `web.default.html` under the path.

Comment: The changes I do for web.default.html will show up for actual mvc project template too which is not expected.

Comment: Actually, this page itself acts as a guidance page and the form does not exist in the current project. And Microsoft didn't extend the page. So I'm sorry to tell you it's not available through API.